# Deploy MVC5 application in azure

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have create mvc5 application (web UI with sql server and entity framework) which is working
as expected, now I want to deploy it in azure ,what it the simplest way to do that?

Currently the application work with SQL DB how should I change it to work with
azure sql Db ,what are the steps...

im using VS2013 premium for web

Thanks!

Comment: Search the web for "deploy ASP.NET MVC to Azure", click the first hit: [How to Deploy a Windows Azure Web Site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/), profit.

Comment: @CodeCaster I want to re-use my mvc project is it possible in vs2013,I dont want to create it from scratch...

Comment: Yes of course you can. Please show exactly what you're having trouble with. Does Azure give you any errors, have you tried anything? See also [How to: Connect to Windows Azure SQL Database Using ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336243.aspx).

Comment: @CodeCaster - I want to try it now,I didnt do anything yet because I dont want to destroy something by mistake...currently the mvc project is working fine...I have azure account.can you please help with the steps...

Comment: You don't have to have the database in Azure to use an Azure Web Application. Be aware that Azure SQL Databases have some different characteristics to an on-site version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Login to your windows Azure account
2. Create a SQL Database on Azure
3. Map database to your new created website
4. Download PublishSettings for your website
5. Visual Studio: Right click on your MVC Solution and choose publish
6. Choose import and select the downloaded publishsettings
7. Connection: choose the provided azure connectionstring to your database
8. click publish

You can also login to your azure account after clicking on Publish in VS. Then you don´t need to download your publishsettings. Choose the website you want to deploy to, select the connectionstring and publish.

Hope this will fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Jkone voted up!,when I create db in VS i just enter new query for the table like follows http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/setting-up-database my question is how should I do this new query in azure

Comment: You have to map your current ip address to your Azure Account. Then You can use the serveraddress from connectionstring and connect to database by visualstudio or SQL Managementstudio. Then create your tables with this Script.